# How to exclude a folder of specs from running while executing `rspec spec`?

Tags: rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

I currently have a folder called `QA` within the `spec` folder that contains capybara tests. The `QA` folder is primarily meant to be run by the QA team. Because of this, I do not want these specs to be run while executing `rspec spec`. Instead, I only want them to be run while executing `rspec spec -t ~all`. What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify an exclusion pattern

```
rspec --exclude-pattern spec/QA/*.rb
```

or you could tag all the QA tests with a specific tag (`qa` perhaps) and then exclude that tag

```
rspec -t ~qa
```